# xlsxwriter error while updating a cell using worksheet.write

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe, xlsxwriter

I am getting error from the `worksheet.write('A1', 'My Title', title_format)` line in my code below.

It is giving the error:

> TypeError: 'Series' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed

How do I resolve the issue? My requirement is to update a specific row in newly created Excel sheet.

```
df = pd.read_excel('C:\\test\\read.xlsx')
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('C:\\test\\test.xlsx',engine='xlsxwriter')
newdf.to_excel(writer, startrow=2, sheet_name='Sheet1', index = False)
workbook = writer.book
worksheet = writer.sheets['Sheet1']
title_format = workbook.add_format(
        {'font_name': 'Calibri', 'bold': True, 'font_size': 16, 'font_color': '#250038', 'text_wrap':
False})
worksheet.write('A1', 'My Title', title_format)
writer.save()
```

Comment: I ran your program, with a few minor changes, and it worked as expected. I would suggest that you update the program to one that shows the issue and also put the full stack trace at the end of the question.

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: This code works at my end  if I remove " worksheet.write('A1', 'My Title', title_format)" line